# Having issues splitting string into chunks in C for cipher project

Tags: c, string, substring

I'm working on a cybersecurity program where I need to split a string of plaintext into blocks of a certain size. The code I currently have does not work but is close. Certain letters are either skipped, or the blocks end up being larger than the block size. Additionally, characters appear that are not represented in the plaintext, but I am unsure of how this could even occur. Could anyone fix this code for me or illuminate where I am going wrong?

Example plaintext: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Example output:

[image: Output]

In the following code, plaintext_len_no_pad is the string of plaintext I want to break into chunks of size size. The size in this case is 2.

```
    // Split plaintext into blocks size n
    int total_blocks = plaintext_len_no_pad / size;
    printf("DEBUG Total blocks: %d\n", total_blocks);
    char blocks[total_blocks][size + 1];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < total_blocks; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            blocks[i][j] = plaintext_no_pad[j + k];
        }
        blocks[i][k + 1] = '\0';
        k += size;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < total_blocks; i++)
    {
        printf("DEBUG Block %d: %s\n", i, blocks[i]);
    }
```

I've tried adjusting where I put the string terminating character, and messed with different ways of splitting the string. This method I whipped up has a bug I cannot figure out. I have looked at related posts, but I have not found one that helped.

Comment: You shouldn't need to make a copy - iterate over the encryption call(s) with an offset into the input data and a length.  The encryption calls should be designed to take an `const unsigned char *` pointer to the beginning of the plaintext to be encrypted, and a `size_t` or similar *unsigned* integer value denoting how many bytes are being processed.  "Can only encrypt `NUL`-terminated strings of printable `char` values" is not a very good encryption system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
blocks[i][k + 1] = '\0';
```

is most definitely not right.

The first iteration of the outer loop it will be equivalent to `blocks[i][1]`. The second iteration it will be equivalent to `blocks[i][size + 1]` which is out of bounds. Then it get further out of bounds.

You should be using

```
blocks[i][size] = '\0';
```

instead.

---

Also be careful if  `plaintext_len_no_pad` is not evenly divisible by `size` (i.e. when `plaintext_len_no_pad % size != 0`).

Comment: This fixed it! I have to pad afterwards so I figured I'd do that after they're split into chunks so I could just append to the last block, although now I'm thinking I should pad before or during.